# Using Coda Hale Meter in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, codahale-metrics

The documentation says that

> Users can create Coda Hale metrics by prefixing their metric names with the appropriate type (e.g. histogram.*, meter.*).

I am taking this to mean that I can use either a Counter or Guage with a metric name of the form "meter.*" and this will work as a meter. I have tried

```
counterService.increment("meter.si.invoice.processing");
```

but when I visit `/manage/metrics` I just see the count and not the metered rate. What is the correct way to use a Coda Hale Meter in Spring Boot. The documentation is not very clear on how the integration works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metrics endpoint is not aware of Codahale stuff. Once you send your metrics there you need to use Codahale tools to extract them (a meter for example doesn't map directly onto Spring Boot metric types, so there's no obvious way to expose them in the way you tried).

Comment: Thanks Dave. Can you point me to where I should be looking in the code to add support for a Codahale meter on the endpoint?

Comment: The metrics endpoint is composed of data from a `@Bean` of type `PublicMetrics`. You should be able to write your own or extend the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

There's some integration magic accomplished by http://www.ryantenney.com/metrics-spring/ that wires codahale metrics into the actuator `/health` endpoint.

With this dependency included,

```
compile 'com.ryantenney.metrics:metrics-spring:3.0.0-RC2'
```

you can "enableMetrics" in your application configuration

```
@EnableMetrics
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    ...
```

This allows you to time each request with the `@timed` annotation:

```
@Timed
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
Foo foo() {
    ...
```

and to have your other interactions with `MetricRegistry` aggregate into the actuator `/health` endpoint.

I've put together an example application which implements this integration:

https://github.com/benschw/consul-cluster-puppet/tree/master/demo

and written a more in depth tutorial here:
http://txt.fliglio.com/2014/10/spring-boot-actuator/